# Get Instagram access token w/out login

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I created an app on Instagram and was able to get a `client_id` and `secret_code`.

I want to display images on my site based on a specific hashtag without needing my user to log in. Every API call requires an access token but I am unable to get without forcing a log in.

This is what I have tried.

[https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[my id]&redirect_uri=[redirect]&response_type=code](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[my%20id]&redirect_uri=[redirect]&response_type=code)

The error I get is

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message":
>   "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

*The redirect URI matches*

Is there a simpler way using PHP or JS to get an access token without invoking a login.

Comment: are you using node.js?

Comment: yes, i am @abhishek

Answer (score 0):

You can use **passport-instagram** package for the authentication. It is the Instagram authentication strategy for passport.

You can find more details here 
http://passportjs.org/